# ids in one app using in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Please, tell me, how many IDs in one app I can create? only 10 000? or 10000 for one IAP?
I'd like to make at least 3 in-app purchases in my application.
and we have a great number of content for sell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is 10000 product IDs. Please refer to [iTunes Connect Developer Guide 7.4](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf):

> You can create up to 10000 separate product IDs assigned to your In-App Purchases per app in iTunes Connect. This number refers to the number of In-App Purchases, not the number of purchase transactions.

Comment: No-no) I'd like to sell some content (5000) for inn-app purchase as consumerable,some content (2000) for subscription.

Comment: Well, if I have a movie with different resolution converted for iPad and iPhone-it  will be different IDs?

Comment: Understood. I think they will be different IDs if you want to sell them separately.